# cannot access or format my USB

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a 16Gb flash drive, was working fine till it just someday stopped working, 
when i plug it the drivers are loaded, but i can't see it the "explorer"
i went to "Disk managment" but this is what i get:
[image: disk]

as u see the flash drive name is (Disque 1) (sorry it in French) and under F:

when i go to cmd and type:
`Formt F:`
i get `Can not open volume for direct access.`
i even tried:
`chkdsk F: /F /X`
i got the same message

i tried to use the DiskPart utility, here s what i've done:

> List disk
>   Select Disk 1
>   Clean
>   i get:
>   Virtual Disk Service Error.
>   There is no media in the device.

Does this means the my drive is broken forever? and there can't be a way to fix it?

USBDeview properties:
[image]

Comment: could try formatting it in Linux. Sometimes Linux "sees" drives easier than windows

Comment: tried with linux it cant detect it either

Comment: I think your drive is heading towards electronic afterlife then.

Comment: but its like one month old!

Comment: warranty / receipt? Who makes it?

Comment: no warranty, the maker is "takeMS"

Comment: Well like the user below said, try using gparted when you get home otherwise your drive is probably toast

Comment: It says **No media.** The drive is probably dead.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know if it's broken is to use gnome-disk-utility with a Linux and mount the device.

If not, try to use gparted and see if the filesystem/partition have any errors.

Can you still see which sdX is your usb-key with gnome-disk-utility, is it even detected ?(also named Disks or palimpsest)

I suggest you to backup and format your usb drive with the dd command, to make your usb key completey erased.

Comment: i dont have linux for now, im not home, is there any other "windows" solution?

Comment: Peut-etre, as-tu ouvert la "gestion de l'ordinateur" en mode administrateur ?

Tu as deja pu avoir une lettre pour ta cle, mais tu ne peut pas voir le contenu, on dirait une erreur de partition. C'est ca qui est bizarre.

Comment: Edit:

Did you opened the "manage" as an administrator (right click) ?

It looks weird, since you still got a letter for your usb key (F:), but still can't see what's inside. It means that the partition is still here with your datas, but that it got problems.

If you can have a Linux, it'll be much more easier to see what problems your partitions may have.